# Is there a way to bypass the inbuilt php functions for sqlinjection

Tags: php, sql-injection

If there is a way to bypass the built-in functions of PHP to protect against SQL injection or I should rely on some other filters rather than depending on built-in functions?

Comment: Any filtering is a form of blacklisting and therefore not recommended (any missing item in the blacklist is a possible attack vector). Have a look at prepared statements (PDO or MySQLi are the APIs you're looking for in case you work with MySQL).

Comment: What built-in functions are you referring to? Generally speaking, only use functions for their specific purpose.

Comment: input sanitation routines are misused regularly.

Answer (score 1):

> should I rely on some other filters to protect against the sql injection

No. Any other filters you might write are not going to be as good as the inbuilt protection (prepared statements, either with `mysqli` or `PDO`), so you should not rely on it at all.

If you want an extra layer of security just in case (not a bad idea, you can never be too save), I would use an intrusion detection system (like `mod_security` for Apache) instead of writing extra filter functions in PHP code myself.

> Is there a way to bypass the inbuilt php functions for sqlinjection

If used correctly, prepared statements or `mysqli_real_escape_string` currently do not have any known vulnerabilities.

There are however known [problems with certain multi-byte character sets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12118602) (this might also be a problem in PDO, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection/12202218#12202218)), and of course forgotten single quotes - in complex queries they are easy to overlook, which is one of the reasons that prepared statements are recommended over escaping.